# Proof Verification, Uniqueness of vector $v$ satisfying $\varphi(u) = \langle u,v\rangle $ for a linear functional $\varphi$.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

I want to prove the uniqueness of the following vector $v$. The existence of the vector is guaranteed.

We know that there exists at least one vector $v$ for every $u$ such that for a linear functional $\varphi$ we have that $$\varphi(u) = \langle u,v \rangle.$$

Suppose there are two vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ such that this holds i.e. $$\varphi(u) = \langle u,v_1 \rangle = \langle u,v_2 \rangle.$$

Then  $$0 = \langle u,v_1 \rangle - \langle u,v_2 \rangle = \langle u , v_1 - v_2 \rangle.$$

Take $u=v_1-v_2$ which implies that $v_1 - v_2 = 0$ or $v_1 = v_2$. I want to say that this is a correct proof but I believe that both $v_1$ and $v_2$ depend on $u$ so that we lose the freedom to set $u=v_1-v_2$ because this is circular.

Is the proof right or is there a flaw? Additionally, is there an easy fix?

---

I must admit that this is not my proof but one I am skeptical of in Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right (P 118, 2nd Ed). Without giving Axler the benefit of the doubt, how do you find my proof?

Comment: Discussion on meta: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/15238/18398

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\;\phi(u)=\langle u,v\rangle\;$ **for all** $\;u\in V\;$ , then it also must be true for $\;u=v_1-v_2\,:\;\;v_1,v_2\;$ do not depend at all on $\;u\;$ . The proof is correct.

Comment: I read the quantifiers wrong. This makes so much more sense now, thanks.

Comment: @user162369 Regarding quantifiers, the sentence "We know that there exists at least one vector v for every u such that for a linear functional φ we have that " in your post is actually saying something very different from what you need.